# Finding size of char parameter

Tags: c

I have a parameter definition such as

```
extract(char open*, char close*)
```

```
extract(char *open, char *close)
```

and in order to find the size of close I was doing:

```
int len = 0;
while(close[len]) close++;
```

The parameter comes from the command line typed by the user.

Afterwards if I try to print `close` it is not there; what happened to it?

Comment: Bad way. Use len as parameter of your function.

Comment: Do you not have access to `strlen`?

Comment: In your example, perhaps you meain `len++` instead of `close++`. And seriously, use `strlen`.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it *bad*, @Someuser.

Comment: @RobKennedy if your char data is null-terminated then it's ok, but who knows.

Comment: I thought that's what you might say, @Someuser. If you can't trust the buffer parameter to be null terminated, though, why can you trust the length parameter? They're both coming from the same caller.

Comment: `char open*`? Did you mean `char *open`?

Comment: @RobKennedy but the caller can get this parameter by own way. Already inside the function you have to rely on strlen only, and unpleasant things can happen sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

You incremented the pointer instead of the index.  You either need to increment `len` instead of `close`, or record the original pointer value in a new variable.

```
int len = 0;
while (close[len] != '\0')
    len++;
```

or:

```
char *original = close;
while (*close != '\0')
    close++;
```

Note that in the second case, the length is `close - original` after the loop terminates.

---

Also (as noted by other people, both in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003196/finding-size-of-char-parameter/23003207?noredirect=1#comment35134067_23003196) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003196/finding-size-of-char-parameter/23003207?noredirect=1#comment35134078_23003196) and an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23003465/15168)), the most effective solution is to use the standard function for the job, `strlen()`, which is often highly optimized by the compiler:

```
int len = strlen(close);
```

Comment: Thank you; that was a "Doh!" moment.

Comment: Isn't `extract(char open*, char close*)` syntactically wrong? I think it should be `extract(char *open, char *close)`.

Comment: @ajay: Yes; it is wrong.  I didn't notice that, but it is quite definitely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan Leffler already has given an excellent answer.

If you are not forbidden from using standard library functions, you can just use:

```
int len = strlen(close);
```